# java jackson XML - how to ignore outer wrappers when parsing?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization, xml-deserialization

The `XML` response from the `API`, I want to parse is something like this:

```
<Envelope>
   <Body>
      <RESULT>
          <SUCCESS>TRUE</SUCCESS>
          <EMAIL>somebody@domain.com</EMAIL>
          ... more stuff...
      </RESULT>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I want to get the fields of `RESULT` into an object.

I could create 3 classes, once for the envelope with the body in it, one for the body with the result in it, and one for the result. But, is there a shortcut?

E.g. just create an object for the result data like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Envelope/Body/RESULT")
public class Result {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SUCCESS")
    private boolean success;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "EMAIL")
    private String Email;
    :
}
```

I would do the parsing in a line like this:

```
return theXmlMapper.readValue(resultPayload, Result.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can read `XML` as tree, find required node and convert it using [`treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode-java.lang.Class-) method. Example:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

JsonNode root = xmlMapper.readTree(xmlFile);
JsonNode node = root.at("/Body/RESULT");
Result result = xmlMapper.treeToValue(node, Result.class);
```

`TRUE` value is not by default parsed as `Boolean` so you need to write custom deserialiser.

This solution **has limitations** which [@M. Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108305/m-justin) points in his comment:

> Per the Jackson XML dataformat documentation, "Tree Model is only
>   supported in limited fashion and its use is recommended against: since
>   tree model is based on JSON information model, it does not match XML
>   infoset". This means that the readTree approach should generally not
>   be used when parsing XML. For instance, the tree model will drop
>   repeated elements with the same name, e.g. when using them to model a
>   list such as:

```
<items><item><id>1</id></item><item><id>2</id></item></items>
```

Comment: Per the [Jackson XML dataformat documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#known-limitations), "Tree Model is only supported in limited fashion and its use is recommended against: since tree model is based on JSON information model, it does not match XML infoset".  This means that the `readTree` approach should generally not be used when parsing XML.  For instance, the tree model will drop repeated elements with the same name, e.g. when using them to model a list such as `<items><item><id>1</id></item><item><id>2</id></item></items>`.

Comment: @M.Justin, I agree. This solution has limitations but for given example it should work properly.

Comment: It'll work properly only assuming that the `... more stuff...` section doesn't contain repeated elements, arrays, collections, mixed content, or anything else that the tree model doesn't support for reading XML.

Comment: @M.Justin, you are totally right. This solution gives good result for simple `XML` payloads in case we have very complex `XML` we need to write some custom deserilaisers/adapters or even use `JAXB` directly. I have added your comment to my answer. I hope you do not have anything against it. In other case please let me know.

Comment: With the caveat this becomes a reasonable tool in the toolbox, though one to use with extreme caution.